# Reduced Row-Echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A one-way ANOVA is given in matrix form as:
$$\begin{bmatrix} y_{11} \\ y_{12} \\y_{13}\\y_{21}\\y_{31}\\y_{32} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix} e_{11} \\ e_{12} \\e_{13}\\e_{21}\\e_{31}\\e_{32} \end{bmatrix}$$

A function of $\beta$ is estimable if  $$\lambda \beta = \rho' X \beta$$ holds. Let $\lambda \beta = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 -2\alpha_3$, we're interesting in finding $\rho$ such that the $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - 2\alpha_3 = \rho' X \beta$

Clearly, this is an underdermined system of equations. How do I rewrite the system in order to applied Reduced Row-Echelon form, I got something like this:
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1& -2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{bmatrix}= \rho' \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3 \end{bmatrix}$